# how to call 2 tables from mysql database with php

Tags: php, mysql

i have 2 tables
page and orders.

```
$ww = mysqli_query($database->connection,"SELECT * FROM `page` 
                                          WHERE `owner` = '$session->u_id'");
while($o = mysqli_fetch_array($ww))
{
    $owner = $o['id'];

    $result = mysqli_query($database->connection,"SELECT * FROM `orders`
                                                 WHERE `owner` = '$owner' ORDER BY id DESC");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
       echo "taxi =".$o['naam']."<br>";
       echo $row['id']."<br>";
    }
}
```

the output is 
23
21
20
17
26
25
24
22
19
Question is How can i sort high to low like
26
25
24
23
22
21
....

Comment: more clean solution is put JOIN ON both tables and as suggested @Epodax ORDER BY ColName DESC

Comment: @everyone downvoting, read the question properly. SheHary has noticed it, this is a problem of running the second query multiple times and wanting to sort all the results by order.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run just one query when selecting from orders, not one query per page (BTW, it helps if you tabulate properly, people can see this then). Even better is to just run one query using a join.

You'll need to post your table structure before we can write any query.

Answer (score -1):

1) you can use inner join to write the query if id column of second table won't be null otherwise use left join

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` inner join page on orders.id = page.id where owner = $session->u_id;
```

2) you can use your first query as sub query and put it in second one like this

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE  exists (SELECT page.id FROM `page` WHERE `owner`     = '$session->u_id' and orders.id=page` WHERE `owner`     = '$session->u_id' and orders.id= )ORDER BY id DESC.id ) ORDER BY orders.id DESC
```

Note : if any syntax error is found the forgive me :)-

Comment: That's horrible sudocode. There's a much nicer way of writing that.

Comment: i meant that there could be a syntax error so i used psuedo word actually its not exactly psuedo code